# Populate matrix with average difference between group data in R

Tags: r, matrix, algebra

I am looking to get the average absolute value of differences between columns of a data frame (i.e. 1. subtract the values from one column from another column, 2. take the absolute values of those differences and then 3. take the mean of those absolute values).  I am then looking to populate a matrix with the results that compare each column with every other column.

For example: I have a data frame that looks like this

```
 df <- data.frame(m1=1:3, m2=1:3+1, m3=1:3+2)
```

I am looking to get a matrix like this (where, for example, column 2, row 1 is populated with the result of:

```
mean(abs(m2-m1))
```

and looks like this:

```
       m1  m2  m3
    m1  0   1   2
    m2  1   0   1
    m3  2   1   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base r:

Since we are taking the absolutes, then the results will always be a symmetric matrix:

first (1)obtain the mean of the absolute differences of the columns, (2)obtain the combinations,(3) create a matrix of dimensions: ncol(df)*ncol(df) and (4) fill in the results:

```
a=combn(df,2,function(x)mean(abs(do.call("-",x))))#1

b= t(combn(ncol(df),2)) #(2)

d = matrix(0,ncol(df),ncol(df))#(3)

d[b]=a
d+t(d)
   [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    2
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    2    1    0
```

you can write a long one line code:

```
  replace(matrix(0,ncol(df),ncol(df)),rbind(i<-t(combn(ncol(df),2)),i[,2:1]),rep(combn(df,2,function(x)mean(abs(do.call("-",x)))),2))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    2
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    2    1    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `diag`

```
abs(df-diag(as.matrix(df)))
#   m1 m2 m3
# 1  0  1  2
# 2  1  0  1
# 3  2  1  0
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer @CPak! Unfortunately your solution doesn't provide the expected results with my data set. My data set has many more rows then columns. That is, does your solution work if the original data frame look like this: `df <- data.frame(m1=1:9, m2=1:9+1, m3=1:9+2)`